# Appending to CMAKE_C_FLAGS

Tags: c++, c, cmake, compiler-flags, linker-flags

I'm using CMake for a project that comes in two versions, one of which requires -lglapi and the other does not.

So far the lines we used look like that:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-O3 -xSSE3 -restrict -lpthread -lX11 -ldrm")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -xSSE3 -restrict -lpthread -lX11 -ldrm")
```

I added an if statement in my CMakeList.txt exactly after those lines:

```
if(SINGLE_MODE)
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} " -lglapi")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} " -lglapi")
endif(SINGLE_MODE)
```

The SINGLE_MODE variable is defined a little up. When I use the message command to display the content of the flag variables it looks alright:

```
-O3 -xSSE3 -restrict -lpthread -lX11 -ldrm -lglapi
```

But when I start compiling I am running into a compile error. Using the verbose mode I realized that in the compiler call it looks like that:

```
-O3 -xSSE3 -restrict -lpthread -lX11 -ldrm; -lglapi
```

I.e. somehow a semicolon got added before adding the -lglapi to the list.

Did anyone here encounter a similar issue and knows a way to fix this issue? I've googled quite a while and studied the CMake manual but couldn't see what I did wrong here.

Thanks,
Tobias

Comment: Did you try `SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lglapi")`?

Comment: @jpo38 You should make an answer and get your deserved reputation :)

Comment: @jpo38, thank you. That did the trick. Should have thought of that myself but after looking at something for too long, you kinda get blind for that.

Comment: Thanks. As I have no CMake installed on my current computer, I could not test. Prefered to have your feedback before posting an untested answer to avoid getting any downvotes....;-). Now ready for upvotes!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to do this instead:

```
if(SINGLE_MODE)
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lglapi")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -lglapi")
endif(SINGLE_MODE)
```

Then, you are sure you append `-lglapi` to the existing `${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}` string. Else, looks like something like a CMake list is being created.

Comment: This is very boilerplate. Is there a shorter solution?

Comment: @nowox: Not any that I'm aware of

Comment: Oh :( I don't really know CMake, but is it not possible to use `list(APPEND`?

Answer (score 21):

Since [CMake 3.4](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html) you do:

```
string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -lglapi")
```

This very handy when you want to set the flags only for one language (C++ in the example above), but if you want to set the same flags for all languages, you can simply do:

```
add_compile_options(-lglapi)
```

Both commands change the flags for the whole directory, if you want to set the flags for only one target, do:

```
target_compile_options(my_lib PUBLIC -lglapi)
```

Flags on a target can either be [PUBLIC, PRIVATE or INTERFACE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/target_compile_definitions.html), allowing to transitively forward the flags from one target to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the particular case where you want to add compiler and linker options (like for --coverage option), the following syntax add the flags to both the linker and compiler:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --coverage")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --coverage")
```

(above commands add --coverage option to both compiler and flags options for C and C++)

Otherwise, if you prefer to use new CMake commands (add_compile_options and  add_link_options), don't forget to add to the linker option too:

```
add_compile_options(--coverage)
add_link_options(--coverage)
```

(above commands add --coverage option to both compiler and flags options for C and C++)